# Beta Reduction - Lambda Calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

We are currently studying Lambda Calculus and have begun Beta Reduction.
Our lecturer is using some notation that was not properly explained to us.
Below is what we have been given.

-reduction:

```
(λ v . e₁) e₂
    ⤳
        [e₂/v]e₁     where [e₂/v] is an operator that replaces each v with an e₂
```

Definition of operator  [e/v]

```
[e/v]v         =   e
[e/v₂]v₁       =   v₁    (when v₁≠v₂, i.e., different identifiers)
[e/v](e₁ e₂)   =   [e/v]e₁ [e/v]e₂
[e₂/v](λ v . e₁) =   (λ v . e₁)
[e₂/v₂](λ v₁ . e₁) = (λ v₁ . [e₂/v₂]e₁)    (when v₁∉FV(e₂))

[x/v] (λ x . f v)
  ⤳ λ x . f x   (WRONG, x∈FV(x)={x})
```

I have tried to find resources online but none seem to use the same notation as him with the '/' sign.
Any explanation of the above code would be very much appreciated.

Comment: In his notation `[e2 / v]e1` means "In `e1`, replace all **free** occurrences of `v` with expression `e2`". Essentially, `v` is a formal parameter, and `e2` is its actual value. (probably) more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Substitution

Comment: Maybe in https://math.stackexchange.com/ you can get a better help :)

Comment: The notation is defined precisely by the two blocks you gave, there is not much more to say about it than that. So what exactly would you like to know?